# gallery thumbs don't resize with windows viewport

Tags: css

I have got this image gallery, [**Clik here to see**](http://www.matteocorona.com/cms_ok/gallery.html.php?page=1).

I need to change the size of thumbinails when I resize the viewport of the windows but as u can see, I can't do that.

I set the max-height & max-width in the css at 100% but nothing, image size doesn't work as I espect.

Where am I wrong with the code?

Here u are my css:

```
ul.gallery {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}

ul.gallery li a:hover{
opacity: 0.6;
}

ul.gallery li{
display: inline;
margin: 5px 5px;

}

li.gallery_item img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the max height/width of your images to 100%, which means that the biggest an image can possibly be is the full viewport area. This does nothing to resize the images when they are smaller than that.

```
li.gallery_item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 23%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Adding a percentage width and height to auto means that your images will scale to fit a row of four on a line.

Experiment with this to get the exact effect you are after.